# Optimization of variable multiplication

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, math, matrix

[This was initially on matrices, but I guess it applies to any variable generically]

Say we have `Var1 * Var2 * Var3 * Var4`.

One of them sporadically changes, which one of them is random.

Is it possible to minimize multiplications?

If I do

```
In case Var1 changes: newVar1 * savedVar2Var3Var4
```

I noticed that then I need to recalculate savedVar2Var3Var4 each time Var2, Var3, Var4 change.

Would that re-calculation of 'saved combinations' defy the purpose?

Comment: "The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet." - Michael A. Jackson ( src: http://wordaligned.org/articles/the-third-rule-of-program-optimisation )

Comment: @pmg - I'm really tired of all the quips on SO about: 1) don't optimize 2) get your O(n) right first [ture, but presumes they didn't do that] 3) Optimization is for experts only [and that's why we ask questions - to learn from experts]

Comment: @phkahler: I'm really tired of people asking pointless micro-optimisation questions.

Comment: @JeremyP: then block questions tagged with optimization.

Comment: @phkahler: Not all questions about optimisation are pointless micro-optimsation questions.  Anyway, my comment was really in response to your comment.  In general the "quips" are right.  It's good advice not to optimise without good reason and then finding a better algorithm is more effective than saving a couple of multiply instructions here and there.

Comment: 1) This question makes a lot of sense if the number of variables gets quite large, because doing the whole product is O(N). 2) I don't like "programming by quips" either. Although sometimes the right answer is "Change the question", I prefer answers that tell how to do something, versus how not to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

For scalars there will probably be no benefit. For largish matrix math, you could compute and store:  Var1*Var2 and Var3*Var4. Your result is the product of these 2 things. Now when one changes you only need to update 2 products instead of 3. Update only one of the 2 stored products depending who change, and update the result.

There you have it, 2 multiplications instead of 3 with each update. This will only benefit you if the common case really is for only one of them to update, but if that's true it should help a lot.

Comment: but if mat1 changes you need to do mat1 X mat2mat3mat4 AND mat1mat2mat3 AND mat1mat2 etc. [because you need to be saving the cases other 3 mats need]

Comment: No, you only recompute A = mat1mat2 and result = A*B where B = mat3mat4. There are only 2 stored products kept around. B is not recomputed when mat1 or mat2 changes.

Comment: oh I see what you mean; you didn't perfect it but optimized it (via limited groups); that's good; accepted.

Comment: I noticed there is a good share of direct copying going on (to save and calculate), would that be significant, at least in some systems?

Comment: You have to compute all those products anyway. A=mat1*mat2, B=mat3*mat4, product=AB. There is no harm in making A and B static and leaving them around. There may be cache issues - reading what you just wrote is always fast while reading what you wrote a while ago may not be. But there should be no copying.

Comment: I think that in this case the cost of if's would be greater than the benefit.

Answer (score 7):

If you had a lot more numbers to multiply or if multiplication was extremely expensive then there is one thing I can think of to do.

If you had a huge number of numbers to multiply then you could separate them into sub-sets and memoize the product of each set.  When a particular set changes, due to one of its members changing, then the memoized product becomes invalid and needs to be recomputed.  You could do this at several levels depending on how expensive multiplication is, how much memory you have available, and how often things change.  How to best implement this in C probably depends on how the variables go about changing -- if an event comes in that says "here is a new value for C" then you can invalidate all products that had C in them (or check that old C actually is different from new C before invalidation).  If they are volatile variables then you will probably just have to compare each of the current values to the previous values (and this will probably take as much or more time as just multiplying on any machine with a hardware multiply instruction).

So, if you have:

```
answer = A * B * C * D * E * F * G * H;
```

then you could do separate those out to:

```
answer = ( (A * B) * (C * D) ) * ( (E * F) * (G * H) );
```

Then, if rather than having this multiplication done directly in C you were to do it on an expression tree:

```
                         answer
                            *
                           / \
                          /   \
                         /     \
                     ABCD       EFGH
                     *             *
                    / \           / \
                   /   \         /   \
                 AB    CD       EF    GH
                 *      *       *      *
                / \    / \     / \    / \
               A   B  C   D   E   F  G   H
```

Then at each level (well maybe just the top few levels) you could have a memoized sub-answer as well as some data to tell you if the variables below it had changed.  If events come in to tell you to change a variable then that could cause the invalidation of the expression to propagate upward upon receipt of the event (or just recompute the memoized sub-answers for each event).  If variables just magically change and you have to examine them to tell that they did change then you have more work to do.

Oh, another way to do this just popped in my head, and I'm ashamed that I didn't think of it earlier.   If you do know the old and new values of a variable that has changed then, as long as the old value was not 0, you could just:

```
new_answer =  (old_answer * new_var) / old_var;
```

In real math this would work, but in computer math this might lose too much precision for your purposes.

Comment: That's actually applicable for the small set too; see accepted answer; unless I miss something. [he made the 4 variables into 2 groups to limit the calculations and still optimize it]

Comment: I noticed there is a good share of direct copying going on (to save and calculate), would that be significant, at least in some systems?

Comment: @Lela Dax: I'm not sure what you are referring to.  I should mention that I wrote my answer with only regular (non-matrix) multiplication in mind.  After rereading the question I'm now rethinking this from an NxN matrix multiplication standpoint.  I may amend or re-answer later.

Comment: It's not important; I just consider that any such solution includes the operation of saving the groups (plus any internal or direct copying during the act of group multiplication), which would not be needed in a direct full multiplication. I suspect it's just obviously faster with the 'group optimization' anyway.

Comment: @Lela Dax: I was thinking more along the lines of something that would specifically take into account the ordering requirements of matrix multiplication.  You cannot commute them the way you can with integer or real multiplication.  I'm considering if with that in mind the subgroups could be formed differently to statistically decrease the number of repeated multiplications.  I remember thinking about stuff like this a million years ago when I studying graphics, and my solutions involved knowledge of what changed often.

Comment: This is a generalization of my answer, and it does work for matrix multiplication - you don't need to commute (which matmul can not do) you just need to associate (which it does do). As you point out, the savings goes up with the number of terms. Here we only recompute 3 products instead of 7 - looks like log(n) vs n. Great question Lela Dax!

Comment: @phkahler: I think people just like my picture (which may also be responsible for me posting after you).  I mentioned commuting only as a restriction (can not do) that might allow for a statistical advantage by grouping differently. I don't know that this can be done, but feel that it might be possible, but I also suspect that the binary tree grouping may optimize for this anyway with randomly distributed changes.

Answer (score 5):

In the first place, micro-optimizations like this are almost never worthwhile.  Time your program to see if there is a performance problem, profile to see where the problem is, and test after making changes to see if you've made things better or worse.

In the second place, multiplications of numbers are generally fast in modern CPUs, while branches can be more expensive.

In the third place, the way you're setting it up, if `Var1` changes, you'll need to recalculate `savedVar1Var2Var3`, `saved Var1Var2Var4`, `saved Var1Var3Var4`, and the whole product.  Obviously, you're better off just recalculating the total.

Comment: I believe this is clearly the case. I started doing an application of it on 4 matrices and the multiplications are already more(!) for one of the cases before even completing its needs.

Comment: And in the case of matrices it'd be even worse (since m1 X m2 != m2 X m1).

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. There is a solution, see mine and possibly others below. Saving ALL the permutations is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you save any time. Every time one of the N variables changes, you need to calculate (N - 1) additional products, right? Say you have A, B, C, and D. A changes, and you have saved the product of B, C, and D, but now you must recalculate your cached ABC, ABD, and ACD products. You are, in fact, doing additional work. A*B*C*D is three multiply operations, while A*BCD, A*B*C, A*C*D, and A*B*D works out to SEVEN.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on how often the values change. With your example, calculating savedVar2Var3Var4 costs you two multiplications, with one additional multiplication each time Var1 changes (or you otherwise need to calculate the total). So: how many times do Var2, Var3, Var4 change, compared to Var1?

If Var1 changes more than about 3 times as often as the others, it should be worth recalculating savedVar2Var3Var4 as needed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the gain is worth the effort, unless your "multiply" operation involves heavy calculations (matrices?).

edit: I've added an example that shows you... it's not worth it :)

```
T multiply(T v1, T v2, T v3, T v4)
{
    static T v1xv2 = v1*v2;
    static T v1xv3 = v1*v3;
    static T v1xv4 = v1*v4;
    static T v2xv3 = v2*v3;
    static T v2xv4 = v2*v4;
    static T v3xv4 = v3*v4;

    static T v1save = v1;
    static T v2save = v2;
    static T v3save = v3;
    static T v4save = v4;

    if v1save != v1 
    {
        v1save = v1;
        v1xv2 = v1*v2;
        v1xv3 = v1*v3;
        v1xv4 = v1*v4;
    }

    if v2save != v2
    {
        v2save = v2;
        v1xv2 = v1*v2;
        v2xv3 = v2*v3;
        v2xv4 = v2*v4;
    }


    if v3save != v3
    {
        v3save = v3;
        v1xv3 = v1*v3;
        v2xv3 = v2*v3;
        v3xv4 = v3*v4;
    }

    if v4save != v4
    {
        v4save = v4;
        v1xv4 = v1*v4;
        v2xv4 = v2*v4;
        v3xv4 = v3*v4;
    }

    return v1xv2*v3xv4;

}
```

Comment: Still on matrices, each recalculation of a 'savedMat2Mat3' etc. would apply load. Would it be worth it?

Comment: Yes, and in the case of matrices it'd be even worse (since m1 X m2 != m2 X m1).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you had a sum of many many variables, like `Sum = A+B+C+D+....` and one of them changed, like `C`. If `C'` is the old value of `C`, then you could just say `Sum += (C-C');`

Same idea for a product: `Product *= C/C';`. (For matrices, they would have to be invertible.)

Of course, you might get creeping roundoff errors, so once in a while you could recalculate the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
var12 = var1*var2;
var34 = var3*var4;
result = var12*var34;
while (values available) {
        get new values;
        if (var1 changes || var2 changes) var12 = var1*var2;
        if (var3 changes || var4 changes) var34 = var3*var4;
        result = var12*var34;
}
```

There is no overload (only change checking) and it can be used for matrices (doesn't rely on commutativity, only associativity).